# A question on surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^4$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces

On surfaces in $\mathbb P^4$,Ellingsrud and Peskine has proved that

> There exists an integer $d_0$ such that for any integer $d>d_0$,any smooth surface of degree $d$ in $\mathbb P^4$ is of  general type.

More precisely,Decker and Schreyer  gave an explicit value on $d_0$

> Every smooth surface in $\mathbb P^4$ of degree $>52$ is of general type.

Later,some non-general type surfaces in $\mathbb P^4$ of degree 15 were found. And it's believed that the best bound $d_0$ is 15,which is the Hartshorne's conjecture.

My question is:

1. Decker and Schreyer proved that theorem in 2000, is there any improvement on the bound $d_0$ recently?
2. I have no idea why $15$ is conjectured as the the best bound although $d_0\geqslant 15$?

Comment: In the first statement, you want the last $d_0$ to be a $d$?

Comment: @JabinDu: Just reread your first question and you will see what Emily Maw means.

Comment: @Emily  Thank you! It's a typo,I have edited it.

Comment: @Sasha Thanks, I have corrected the typo.